# Accessing array elements individually in Golang

Tags: arrays, loops, go

I know this is very basic but i want to know how to access elements individually,the values of Sourceposition and currentarray keep changing, this operation is apart of recursive function.

For example:

```
 var Sourceposition int

var currentarray [8]int

for j:=0;j<len(currentarray);j++
{
  if currentarray[j]==0{
  Sourceposition = currentarray[j+1]}
fmt.Pritnln(Sourceposition)
}

//random statements
```

this gives me a error index out of range, Can someone help me , how to this calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your last iteration (when `j == len(currentarray) - 1` which is 7) you're accessing `currentarray[7]` and then if that equals zero trying to access `currentarray[8]` which is out of range for `[8]int`.

The fix depends on the intended behaviour, it might be that you need to fix your loop invariant to be `j < len(currentarray) - 1`, or, if you want to treat your array in a circular way, you may want to do `Sourceposition = currentarray[(j + 1) % len(currentarray)]`.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/E7yt3p0BbC, this is the code i have and i get this index out range error i cant understand why, In my previous questions i mentioned about what I'm working on, It would be great if you can help.. @Roman Khimov